# Xamarin forms get list items count where property selected true

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to show something like: 
'Selected {items(where selected = true).Count} items'

I have a bindable internal class in the MV which has property IsSelected. How can I get the count of all items where IsSelected is true through XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way that you can do this in XAML other than having this calculated in the VM and reflect it in the View through another (bound) property:

```
using System.Linq

public int SelectedCount  //In xaml just bind to this
{ 
    get => yourList.Count(x => x.IsSelected);
}
```

or if it has to update dynamically, you could do so:

public int SelectedCount { get; set; } //with INotifyPropertyChanged-implementation

```
//Whenever you update your list:
SelectedCount = yourList.Count(x => x.IsSelected);
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCount");
```

Comment: That will work. Thanks. I was wondering if I could make it without creating a new property

Comment: Not with the "IsSelected == true" filter. The basic count can be used through .Count in XAML I believe. Another way is to create a converter, but if its just this one case then the prop is best suited